# How to serve 404 page in Node js + Express App on html5mode(true)?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I configured App routing with `$stateProvider` along with `html5Mode`. To prevent 404 error on page refresh on html5Mode i configure a route as below in express.

```
app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
  res.sendFile('./public/index.html', { root: __dirname });
});
```

with above statement i'm unable to show the 404 page, because all unmatched routes finally serving by above code.

**Example**

```
   http://myhost:3000/my/valid/location 
   ----- working fine-------------

   http://myhost:3000/you/give/any/location
   ----- Always giving index.html page-------
```

Comment: Could this be related to your '*' within app.all?

Comment: @ElementCR, Yes, Application is serving matched routes, ex `localhost:3000/users/list`. If i type `localhost:3000/users/list/some_unknown` index page is getting served

Comment: You need a 404 route in angular with this configuration.  you can't serve a 404 from your server because your server won't know what's valid or not.

Comment: you probably *already* have a 404 route in angular, it's the `otherwise` action of your angular router;  in many configurations, this is just set to `/`, so the app is always available, even when the user inputs invalid sequences.

Comment: @Claies, Thanks. I got an option to handle this with  angular's  `otherWise`. Let me see if i get other solution.